# Insert data from array where $key has a $value

Tags: php

Hi I am new to this so here goes.

I have an array of all of my product items and what we require is a price file per customer, as each customer has different pricing structures.

I am able to successfully create a price file name and retrieve the ID after it has been inserted to the table 1 "Name" now I need to insert the item id and the custom price into Table 2 as well as the id of "Name".

I want to be able to loop through the array of _POST['custprice'] and only insert the item id and custom price if a value was submitted in the _POST.

For example we have 100 items to choose from but the customer only requires 2 of these items, user enters the custom price of the 3 items, we need to then loop through the 100 items and only insert the 3 items that have a value.

Hope this makes sense.

```
$custprice = $_POST['custprice'];

foreach ($custprice as $key => $value) {

  if($value > 0){

  $sql3 = "INSERT INTO price_file(id,prod_code,price)
            VALUES($lastid,'$key',$value)";

  $result2 = $db->query($sql3);

  if($result2){
    $prompt = 'worked';
    return $prompt;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a snippet from the array

```
    [custprice] => Array
    (
        [BACC] => 
        [SHC] => 
        [BML] => 
        [HTL] => 90
    )
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The `return` in your `foreach` will immediately cease iterating.

Comment: You also are open to SQL injections. If `$value` is not an integer your query will fail.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I can see my mistake there.